# How to get elements in one Flux that does not appear in another Flux

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

I am new to Spring Reactive Project. There was a problem in use. 
I have two Flux, One has more elements, such as

```java
Flux<Integer> bigFlux = Flux.range(1, 10);
```

And another likes

```
Flux<Integer> smallFlux = Flux.just(3, 7);
```

How can I get the elements in bigFlux that not appears in smallFlux?
I don't know which operator to use.

I have tried:

```java
Flux<Integer> flux = bigFlux.filterWhen(one -> smallFlux.hasElement(one).map(a->!a));
```

But this is not wise, I got smallFlux through complex operations, such as querying the database, flatMap operations. In this way, how many elements in bigFlux, how many times these operations will be repeated.

In fact, smallFlux is obtained in this way.

```
Flux<File> usedFile = repository.findAll()
                .flatMap(one -> {
                    List<File> used = someMethods(one);
                    return Flux.fromIterable(used);
                });
```

Are there other better solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a cleaner and faster solution

```
final Flux<Integer> bigListFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3);

final Flux<Integer> smallListFlux = Flux.just(3, 5, 6);

Mono.zip(bigListFlux.collectList(), smallListFlux.collectList(), (bigList, smallList) -> {

  bigList.removeAll(smallList);

  return bigList;
}).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).map(element -> {

  System.out.println("element = " + element);

  return element;
}).subscribe(); // do not use subscribe/block in actual production code.
```

I've used the following variant of `Mono.zip`

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-